# How to set up per second billing for my ec2 instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am using `boto3` to manage ec2 instances from my app.

However, I don't know how to specify to aws that I want on demand ec2 instances billed per second.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

In AWS there is no such thing to specify how to be billed. If you start an on-demand EC2 instance, you will be billed per hour and for partial hours you will be billed per second.

From AWS [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/):

> Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance, from the time an instance is launched until it is terminated or stopped. Each partial instance-hour consumed will be billed per-second for Linux Instances and as a full hour for all other instance types.

There are ways to achieve lower price per hour (example: use spot instances), but there is no setting to be changed on how you will be priced.